# tinyMCE build without css

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, tinymce

I clone https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce

and run builder:
`grunt bundle --themes modern --plugins table,paste`...

It works fine,
but when I run `tinymce.full.min.js`, it loads from server css files:

```
skins/lightgray/skin.min.css
skins/lightgray/content.min.css
```

I have in my project common min.css file, where i can include those files

So, can i disable loading those css files from minified file with builder or do it in an other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the theme you want and define an own one if you like:

```
theme: 'my_theme',
```

or you can choose an other already existing theme like this one: https://pixabay.com/de/blog/posts/a-modern-custom-theme-for-tinymce-4-40/